# How to write API to find international TimeZone

Tags: php, asp.net

I need to write a API in `php` to get the timezone. I did some research found

1. [google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro).
2. [Timezonedb.com](https://timezonedb.com/api)
3. [time-zone-api](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/api/time-zone-api.aspx)

   I need to write API in php and ASP.net to get the TimeZone. It will be used for commercial site. I am looking for free service for this task.

If some one can help me the right functions to do this task in php or asp.net.

I would still appreciate that.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @PrerakSola : Thanks for responding. So far I just have done analysation.I have yet to implement and try this things. I just wanted to know if there is other ways to do this without using third party API for commercial purpose. Just need the logic for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php DateTimeZone Class as the base Class for your API.